# Alphanumeric Sorting in PostgreSQL 9.4

Tags: sql, postgresql, natural-sort

I've a table in PostgreSQL 9.4 database in which one of the column contains data both integer and alphabets in following format.

```
1
10
10A
10A1
1A
1A1
1A1A
1B
1C
1C1
2
65
89
```

Format is, it starts with a number then an alphabet then number then alphabet and it goes on. I want to sort the field like below,

```
1
1A
1A1
1A1A
1B
1C
1C1
2
10
10A
10A1
65
89
```

But when sorting 10 comes before 2. Please suggest a possible query to obtain desired result.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
ORDER  BY (substring(column_name, '^[0-9]+'))::int     -- cast to integer
          ,coalesce(substring(column_name, '[^0-9_].*$'),'')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this query breaks if number comes after alphabet, pl check the output. https://ibb.co/cZ6kJw